# How to deal with longestCommonPrefix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, algorithm, while-loop

I am trying to resolve the LongestCommonPrefix problem on leet code.
I am stuck to pass this test :

```
["a","a","b"]
```

The expected output is "", but the result is : 'a'.

Here is my code :

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs):
        """
        :type strs: List[str]
        :rtype: str
        """
        prefix_list = list()
        j = 0
        i = 0
        
        min_ = min(strs, key=len)
        if len(list(set(strs))) == 1:
            return strs[0]
        
        
        while i < len(strs) and 0 < len(strs) < 201:
            word = strs[i] 
        
            if  len(word) < 201 and word != "":

                if i + 1 < len(strs) and j < len(min_)  and word[j] == strs[i+1][j]:
                    prefix_list.append(word[j])
                    j += 1
                    i += 1
                else:
                    return u''.join(prefix_list)
            
            else:
                return ""
```

I tried to check if len(prefix_list) is equal to i but no effective result..

Comment: Don't use a while loop, use a for loop and iterate through each word. Keep track of the current prefix and check it against each word as you iterate through them.

Comment: The issue here is that you're appending to the longest common prefix when neighboring words match at the current index `j`, but since you need the longest common prefix among all words, the correct approach would be to update when *all* words match at `j`. I'd suggest writing out your algorithm/pseudocode, then writing code that mimics the pseudocode and commenting when necessary to avoid/find bugs like these. I'd also recommend looking into `itertools` or `zip` in python to make the iteration of multiple arrays/strings in parallel more pythonic.

Comment: Why reinvent the *wheels* - just one line:  ```return os.path.commonprefix(strs)``` ;-)